# WebSocket on default VS non-default port

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

In web there are two ways to open websockets:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.com");
```

and

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8000");
```

Which one is better in terms of performance? As I understand in the first case browser reuses an already opened connection (the one which `index.html` was loaded from), whereas in the second case browser needs to open a new connection (which requires TCP/TLS negotiation). So the first option should be faster, am I right?

Comment: In the first case, it will use the default port, which is I believe 443 for WSS. In both cases it will open a new connection.

Comment: if you want to be sure you can use console.time() and console.timeEnd() and check the run time with both, but I strongly suspect that it's going to be the same.